# How did Kepler know that orbits are elliptical?

Tags: physics, astronomy, celestial-mechanics, 17th-century, kepler

Suppose I was living in his time. How would Kepler explain that the orbits are elliptical?

Since none of his 3 laws explain why orbits are elliptical, I assume he must have had other reasons to believe why orbits are elliptical. Also, calculus had not yet been invented. So, how did he do that? How did he know that the distance to the Sun was changing, and that the velocity of the planet was changing to compensate for that? Was it solely because of the observational data provided by Tycho Brahe?

Can someone provide the details of his thinking on this?

Comment: He made a lot of calculations, based on Tycho's observations.

Comment: You can see [Johannes Kepler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Kepler) and the bibliography there; notably: Max Caspar, [Kepler](https://books.google.it/books?id=cYQUAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Alexandre Koyré, [The Astronomical Revolution: Copernicus-Kepler-Borelli](https://books.google.it/books?id=dAzVuXqnbrEC&printsec=frontcover), Bruce Stephenson, [Kepler's physical astronomy](https://books.google.it/books?id=EpDTBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Have you read [Wikipedia's article about Kepler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Kepler#Astronomia_nova)? It describes his process in much detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did Kepler arrive at his planetary laws based on Mars's orbit alone?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/did-kepler-arrive-at-his-planetary-laws-based-on-marss-orbit-alone)

Comment: Calculus had sorta been **discovered** (not invented -- the principles always existed)  before, and then forgotten  https://www.sciencenews.org/article/prayer-archimedes

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/366401/5441). Please only ask a question on one site, so that the answers are in one place.